# CSS forms (for relative newbie) or methodology easy to implement alongside jQuery and ASP Classic

Tags: css, forms, asp-classic

I'm having one of those procrastination overstimulated panic attacks about choosing a method of doing forms in CSS that work well alongside JQuery (on Classic ASP or .NET) and are accessible.

I've been hit with the accessibility/compliance thing pretty hard now, so I'm terrified of making the wrong choice. I've got to produce prototypes here soon and I'm freaking.

I've done some CSS layout and debugging, but haven't really done much with DIV and FLOAT with forms that are more than one field (not like phone or zip).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in accessible forms, have a look at these two sites:

http://www.jimthatcher.com/webcourse8.htm

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms

Basically, you want to do the following, where possible...

1. include a `type` on each `input`... helpful for screenreaders
2. include a `title` on each `element`... also helpful for screenreaders
3. use `labels` and `inputs` in close relation to each other (side by side or one on top of the other)
4. make sure that users can tab through the form, that is, they do not need a keyboard to navigate
5. ensure that your css allows for elements to show focus when they receive focus.

Also, a bit of client-side (e.g., javascript) validation is also very helpful.

You may want to check out some of the HTML5 form improvements too, which also help with accessibility.

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/forms.html

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need anything of this sort. Use the `<form>` and the `<label>`s themself to layout your form.

http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/pnm8w/

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most important thing you can do is to make sure to explicitly associate labels with their control by setting the [labels' for attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.9)

```
<label for="name">Name</label><input type="text" id="name />
```

In dotnet this is accomplished by using the [AssociatedControlID property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.associatedcontrolid.aspx)

```
<asp:Label AssociatedControlID="String" />
```